# Get post meta data of custom post type

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, meta-boxes

I create custom post type "portfolio" and create custom meta box with value key "_portfolio_name_value_key". but when I try to retrieve the saved value in frontend it did not show.
 i used this code:
**`<?php get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_portfolio_name_value_key' ); ?>`** in single-portfolio.php page,

however title, featured image, custom taxonomy and content had no problem displaying.
Here is full code I used:

```
<?php 
                    if ( have_posts() ) :
                    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>


         <div class=row>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8 col-sm-8">
               <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme project-detail-carousel"id=project_detail>
                  <div class=project-detail-item><img alt=p-detail src="<?php the_post_thumbnail(''); ?>"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
               <div class=project-detail-1>
                  <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                  <ul>
                     <li><span>Client:</span><?php get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_portfolio_name_value_key' ); ?>
                     <li><span>Category:</span> <?php the_terms( $post->ID, 'field' ); ?>
                     <li><span>Status:</span> <?php get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_portfolio_status_value_key' ); ?>
                     <li><span>Tags:</span> <?php the_terms( $post->ID, 'ptag' ); ?>
                     <li><span>Date:</span> <?php get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_portfolio_date_value_key' ); ?>
                  </ul>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="row mt-50">
            <div class=col-md-12>
               <div class=project-detail-1-info>
                  <h3>A little About This Project</h3>
                  <div class=text-content>
                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php 
        endwhile;
    endif;      

     ?>
```

Comment: Hey use this link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/

Comment: thanks for respond but i used same code, it did not work, in my case i update code as <?php get_post_meta( $post_id, $key='_portfolio_name_value_key', $single=true ); ?>

Comment: You are in the loop so you need to put get_the_ID() function in place of $post->ID

Comment: It did not work, however, title, thumbnail, content, taxonomy are working with  $post->ID as in above

Comment: Please go to post_meta table recheck custom field.

Comment: i did not follow where should i check, in custom post type code in function.php

Comment: Did you check the meta_keys are correct that you are using?

Comment: add just global $post after while

Answer (score 1):

As it seems you are using a loop. In the loop, you should use `get_the_ID()` function.

**From:**

```
<?php get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_portfolio_name_value_key' ); ?>
```

**To:**

```
<?php get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_portfolio_name_value_key' ); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

`get_post_meta()` returns a value instead of echo it.
So you need to echo it like this:

```
<?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_portfolio_date_value_key' ,true ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:-

```html
<?php 

$wpb_all_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'post', 'post_status'=>'publish', 'posts_per_page'=>-1));
                    if ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) { ?>
 <div class=row>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8 col-sm-8">
               <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme project-detail-carousel"id=project_detail>
                  <div class=project-detail-item><img alt=p-detail src="<?php the_post_thumbnail(''); ?>"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
               <div class=project-detail-1>
                  <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                  <ul>
                     <li><span>Client:</span><?php get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_portfolio_name_value_key', true ); ?>
                     <li><span>Category:</span> <?php the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'field' ,true ); ?>
                     <li><span>Status:</span> <?php get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_portfolio_status_value_key' ,true ); ?>
                     <li><span>Tags:</span> <?php the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'ptag' ,true ); ?>
                     <li><span>Date:</span> <?php get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_portfolio_date_value_key' ,true ); ?>
                  </ul>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="row mt-50">
            <div class=col-md-12>
               <div class=project-detail-1-info>
                  <h3>A little About This Project</h3>
                  <div class=text-content>
                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
        </div>
  <?php wp_reset_postdata(); }?>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Office Painting – the Easy Way</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">12 Questions to Ask – <i>Before</i> You Hire a Painter</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://route1paintingandwindows.com/price-service-sketchy-dudes/">Price, Service &amp; Sketchy Dudes</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://route1paintingandwindows.com/top-3-must-haves-when-hiring-a-paint-contractor/">Top 3 Must-Haves When Hiring A Paint Contractor</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Top 5 Uninsured Contractor What-if’s</a></li>
</ul>
```